# Select Filter with Nested JSON Array in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server-2012

Here is some same data's

```
{ "Title" : "111", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "111", "SecondGroup" : [{ "FirstTextArea" : "11", "Radio" : "First", "CheckBox" : "{C}", "FileUpload" : "" }, { "FirstTextArea" : "22", "Radio" : "Second", "CheckBox" : "{C++}", "FileUpload" : "" }, { "FirstTextArea" : "33", "Radio" : "Third", "CheckBox" : "{.Net~Java}", "FileUpload" : "" }], "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "VlFteG45aFlHNExVWndpcnh1RHVoQT09", "Age" : "11111111111", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "111111111" }, { "Address" : "S0NBTWhUMFB4QzdlaHh5aHFVUi9HQT09", "Age" : "22222", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "us", "SecondTextArea" : "222222" }] }
{ "Title" : "AAAAAA", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "AAAAA", "FirstTextArea" : "AAAAA", "Radio" : "Second", "CheckBox" : "{C++~.Net~Java}", "FileUpload" : "", "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "RWxqTVF1RE9IMHRGOHhzelRsdTZidz09", "Age" : "1000", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "100" }, { "Address" : "RE5HbFU5MFlEK3pFekQvR1dYWVVVQT09", "Age" : "200", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "200" }, { "Address" : "STM4d0xwYTR4Zjh6eXRFWFkvbnhSZz09", "Age" : "300", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "300" }] }
{ "Title" : "SampleData", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "test", "FirstGroup" : [{ "FirstTextArea" : "1", "Radio" : "First", "CheckBox" : "{C}", "FileUpload" : "" }, { "FirstTextArea" : "2", "Radio" : "Second", "CheckBox" : "{C++}", "FileUpload" : "" }], "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "U1FGVVNXTEZyVGlQVHozQ29CZUVUZz09", "Age" : "", "TestField" : "A1", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "A1" }, { "Address" : "U2xMV0RXdmN3ak1qbm11Qml2OGNpQT09", "Age" : "", "TestField" : "B1", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "B1" }, { "Address" : "STRWRVZxYWliNFRvRGNtSFNlbHMzQT09", "Age" : "", "TestField" : "C1", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "C1" }] }
{ "Title" : "A1B1", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "A2B2", "FirstTextArea" : "1212", "Radio" : "First", "CheckBox" : "{C~C++}", "FileUpload" : "", "Address" : "", "Age" : "111", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "111" }
{ "Title" : "ABC", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "aa", "FirstTextArea" : "aa", "Radio" : "First", "CheckBox" : "{C++}", "FileUpload" : "", "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "VzRSTU5iSGZBa3AvOGV6NXlTSjZiUT09", "Age" : "234", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "1" }, { "Address" : "T2YvcWgwNkZCV29GSHIrcDd4UXVVdz09", "Age" : "33", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "us", "SecondTextArea" : "2" }] }
{ "Title" : "", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "", "FirstGroup" : [{ "FirstTextArea" : "", "Radio" : "", "CheckBox" : "{}", "FileUpload" : "" }], "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "", "Age" : "", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "--Select--", "SecondTextArea" : "" }] }
{ "Title" : "", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "", "FirstGroup" : [{ "FirstTextArea" : "", "Radio" : "", "CheckBox" : "{}", "FileUpload" : "" }], "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "", "Age" : "", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "--Select--", "SecondTextArea" : "" }] }
```

i want filter JSON where Age='33'

Output like

```
{ "Title" : "ABC", "Attachment" : "", "Name" : "aa", "FirstTextArea" : "aa", "Radio" : "First", "CheckBox" : "{C++}", "FileUpload" : "", "Groupitem" : [{ "Address" : "VzRSTU5iSGZBa3AvOGV6NXlTSjZiUT09", "Age" : "234", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "ind", "SecondTextArea" : "1" }, { "Address" : "T2YvcWgwNkZCV29GSHIrcDd4UXVVdz09", "Age" : "33", "TestField" : "", "Country" : "us", "SecondTextArea" : "2" }] }
```

Note : JSON will be generated dynamically, so we don't know the index of key 'Age'

Comment: If you don't know where the value is going to be,  I suggest fixing the process that creates the JSON so that it's more consuimable.

Comment: JSON will be generated dynamically, we don't know the position of any key. For example key 'Age' is placed either inside array or nested array or it may available as open json(not an array item). In these case we need to filter json based any one key and value like 'Age'='33'

Comment: *"JSON will be generated dynamically*" Which is why I said " I suggest fixing the process that creates the JSON so that it's more consuimable."